# AutoIt script to close a PDF file window

Tags: pdf, webdriver, autoit

Greetings !
              I use selenium WebDriver to automate the browser , and in one of the particular flow when i click on a button it opens a PDF file in the UI...This PDF file i wont be able to handle with the webdriver commands..... fine.. So i go with the option of AutoIT to close this PDF file window and to proceed further with the webdriver commands present in the same java class....

But it looks not working for me , the autoIt script which i execute is not closing the pdf window..

I tried it many times by trying diff options,for ex: with scripts something below ..but no luck... Please share me if you are aware of how to handle this...

```
WinWait("[CLASS=AcrobatSDIWindow]") WinActivate("[CLASS=AcrobatSDIWindow]")
```

WinClose("[CLASS=AcrobatSDIWindow]")

Many Thanks in advance ~Musaffir

Comment: You should use the return value of `WinWait` like `$win = WinWait("[CLASS=AcrobatSDIWindow]")` and check probably with `WinFlash($win)` whether you received the correct window handle... And use it with the `WinClose` function afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks working well for me now , autoit script with almost same line of codes as i posted in the question

```
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")
WinActivate("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")
WinClose("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")
```

we need to run this script first in selenium java class, so when a pdf window comes in the UI,it just closes it

To run in the java code use:  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\Auto_IT_Scripts_New\\Close_PDF_File.exe");`

This will run the script in the system... and the script run stops once the file has been closed

Thanks,
Musaffir